# RxJava operator for single event or Timeout event

Tags: java, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a scenario like i am expecting a event within a specific time. If no event occur within a specific time than i also need to take action after that time.

For example i am expecting a valid event within `3 sec`, if no event occur withing `3 sec` i need to take another action.

For this i have use `timeout` but after getting a valid event timeout also firing an event for `TimeoutException`.

```
    ResultStatusRepo.resultStatus
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .timeout(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            Timber.i("Result valid status: $it" )
        }, {
            Timber.e("Error: ${it.message}")
            if (it is TimeoutException) {
                Timber.i("Timeout for result")
            }
        })
```

Here `resultStatus` is type `Observable<Boolean>`

If i get result after 1 sec than after 3 sec again i get `TimeoutException` in `onError`. I know `timeout` behaves like this. For my scenario which operator suits most. Is there any other way around.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

**ResultStatusRepo**

```
private val ownResultStatus = BehaviorSubject.create<Boolean>()
val resultStatus : Observable<Boolean> get() = ownResultStatus
```

Comment: Should the timeout only be valid for the first item and not for the others? If so, there is an overload method overload for this kind of ues-case.

Comment: @HansWurst should emit only one item or timeout

Comment: Maybe, you could chain the `timeout()` operator with an `onErrorResumeNext()` operator to perform the action you wish to do when a timeout occurs?

Comment: What is `resultStatus`? Can in emit multiple items eventually? Do you want to take only the first item from `resultStatus`?

Comment: @akarnokd `resultStatus` is `Observable<Boolean>` but actual source is `BehaviorSubject.create<Boolean>()` . So `resultStatus` can emit multiple but i am only want to take current event or the first one. @akarnokd I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

What about following solution? Will it help you?

```
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Function
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.schedulers.TestScheduler
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

class TimeOutOverload {
    lateinit var sched: TestScheduler
    lateinit var merge: Observable<String>

    @BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        sched = TestScheduler()
        merge = Observable.merge(
            Observable.timer(6, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched),
            Observable.timer(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched)
        ).map { "42_${it}" }
    }

    @Test
    fun `65671148 - times out on first`() {
        val test =
            merge.timeout(
                Observable.timer(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched),
                Function<String, Observable<String>> { _ -> Observable.never<String>() }
            ).test()

        sched.advanceTimeBy(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        sched.triggerActions()

        test.assertError(TimeoutException::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun `65671148 - no timeout after first value arrived`() {
        val test =
            merge.timeout(
                Observable.timer(7L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched),
                Function<String, Observable<String>> { _ -> Observable.never<String>() }
            ).test()

        sched.advanceTimeBy(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        sched.triggerActions()

        test.assertValues("42_0", "42_0")
    }
}
```

The `timeout` operator will only fire on the first element. All other elements will pass through.

Regarding:

> if no event occur withing 3 sec i need to take another action.

You have to use an `onError`*-Operator to provide a fallback value, when the `TimeoutException` happens.

Note:
I used different values from your example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using `RxJava2` . I didn't checked `RxJava3` yet. Solution with `RxJava2` will helpful to me. Will check your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbuYousuf, it works the same with RxJava2, only the packages are different in this example.